# Navigation Controller strategy with an Address Book picker

Tags: cocoa-touch, addressbook

So I'd like to have a user select a contact using the People Picker and THEN enter some custom data once a contact has been successfully selected. Simple enough.

My question is where is the best place for my <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>?  Should I put it in the RootViewController which is the delegate to the view with the button that will initiate this process? Then once an address book contact has been picked THEN pass that ABRecordID into my next view controller (AddPersonViewController) that knows more about the extra goodies in my Person class and will handle the addition of the custom data I want to associate with said address book contact...

OR, is it considered better to fire up the AddPersonViewController but before it displays immediately throw up the modal ABPeoplePickerNavigationController onto the stack as well

Wondering if anyone has any sage advice either pro or con with this?
 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former.

Create views and controllers in the order you will use them. When finished with one transition to the next.